# Python-3, Pandas datareader and Yahoo Error RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL

Tags: python, stock, yahoo-finance

I am trying to use yahoo finance for importing stock data
I am using the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight")
%matplotlib inline

# For reading stock data from yahoo
from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader

# For time stamps
from datetime import datetime
```

It is running fine.

```
    from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override() # <== that's all it takes :-)

# download dataframe
# The tech stocks we'll use for this analysis
tech_list = ['WIPRO.BO', 'INFY.BO', 'TCS.BO', 'HAPPSTMNDS.BO']

# Set up End and Start times for data grab
end = datetime.now()
start = datetime(end.year - 1, end.month, end.day)


#For loop for grabing yahoo finance data and setting as a dataframe

for stock in tech_list:   
# Set DataFrame as the Stock Ticker

      globals()[stock] = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stock, start, end)
```

While running below mentioned code I am getting an error:

```
company_list = ['WIPRO.BO', 'INFY.BO', 'TCS.BO', 'HAPPSTMNDS.BO']
company_name = ["Wipro", "Infosys", "Tata_Consultancy_Services", "Happiest_Minds_Technologies"]

for company, com_name in zip(company_list, company_name):
    company["company_name"] = com_name
    
df = pd.concat(company_list, axis=0)
df.tail(10)
```

Error Message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-6-4753fcd8a7a3> in <module>
      3 
      4 for company, com_name in zip(company_list, company_name):
----> 5     company["company_name"] = com_name
      6 
      7 df = pd.concat(company_list, axis=0)

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Please help me in solving this.

Thanks a lot ^_^

Comment: The "company" in the for loop you have written is a string from the company_list you have defined above. You are trying to assign a new value to the string(assuming it to be a dict), that's why you are getting the error.

Comment: So, what should I do to it make it error free?

Comment: well, that depends on what output do you want. what is the end goal?

Comment: The end goal is, after getting the data for the ticker. I will make an ARIMA model for forecasting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARIMA is used for forecasting univariate time-series data. Not sure which feature you want to forecast. Came up with this one below:(Upvote if it works for you!)

```
#For loop for grabing yahoo finance data and setting as a dataframe
lt=[]
for stock in tech_list:   
# Set DataFrame as the Stock Ticker

  temp_df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stock, start, end)
  temp_df = temp_df.reset_index()
  lt.append(temp_df)
# Each element in the list is a DataFrame
df = pd.concat([lt[0],lt[1],lt[2],lt[3]], axis=0)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df.head())


Output:

        Date        Open        High        Low         Close       Adj Close   Volume
    0   2020-07-09  224.850006  224.850006  219.800003  221.600006  221.103027  198245
    1   2020-07-10  221.600006  223.449997  219.449997  222.000000  221.502121  109461
    2   2020-07-13  224.000000  229.000000  222.750000  227.550003  227.039673  385205
    3   2020-07-14  229.000000  231.600006  224.199997  225.050003  224.545288  449975
    4   2020-07-15  237.000000  265.500000  233.800003  262.950012  262.360291  6313161
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the fix_yahoo_finance package has been changed to yfinance. So please try this code.

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override() # <== that's all it takes :-)

# download dataframe
# The tech stocks we'll use for this analysis
tech_list = ['WIPRO.BO', 'INFY.BO', 'TCS.BO', 'HAPPSTMNDS.BO']

# Set up End and Start times for data grab
end = datetime.now()
start = datetime(end.year - 1, end.month, end.day)


#For loop for grabing yahoo finance data and setting as a dataframe

for stock in tech_list:   
# Set DataFrame as the Stock Ticker

      globals()[stock] = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stock, start, end)
```

The get_data_yahoo() method returns a pandas dataframe. So depending on what you want to do you can generate list of dataframes and concatenate the list together.